# Elastic search group two fields to single field without copy_to parameter

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, match-phrase

**The problem**

I have object employee with two separate properties:

- FirstName
- LastName

For relevant ordering I must use ***match_phrase*** parameter, cause ***match_phrase*** provides better relevance depending on word order.

I tried use ***copy_to*** parameter for copy *first* and *last* names to *eng_full_name* field, but unfortunately as I understand ***copy_to*** doesn't provide tokens ordering, that important in phrasal matching.

And request below not working

```
    GET agreements/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "eng_full_name": {
            "query": "Kimberly Smith",
            "slop": 4, 
            "boost": 25
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I can't don't use ***match_phrase*** because ***slop*** parameter required in the context of the task.

Is it possible to configure ***copy_to*** order. If no does i have some alternative way?

Comment: You could try to combine these two fields when indexing data, don't know how you do this if, you are indexing with NEST help you could just add extra property into your POC type like `public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}"`.

Comment: Yes, made the same, seems like a single solution. Thought that nest has some options for index configuration for avoiding changes in model